# Why are My tests failing on Travis yet passing locally

Tags: python

I added validate_mail and also installed py3dns to check if the email the user signs up with is valid(like their emails are not fake). The tests seem to pass locally but one fails via Travis build remotely(specifically the test that checks if the user can create an account with a valid email). Any advice will be very much appreciated on how to stop it from failing remotely.

Comment: Look at the error logs. With all the Travis tests I've seen, it checks python 2.7 and 3.x. In the cases I've failed, the 2.7 faled because the syntax I used was only for 3.x.

Comment: The code syntax is up to py 3.x standards and yet it still fails, I think the test failing is because remotely the email isn't getting verified like locally and I dont know why travis isnt allowing that email for that particular test to be verified